# Not able to load JS library with Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm trying to authenticate google vision api with electron and it seems like the google vision api can't find the required libraries so it gives me these errors.

[image]

I added the node module using

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/vision
```

and this is how I'm trying to initialize it

```
var vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

var visionClient = vision({
    keyFileName: './file.json',
    projectId: 'project-name'
});
```

Comment: Do you use it as a node module? Provide some code example and the way you run it

Comment: ummm what about that red error at the bottom?

Comment: Just edited the post to answer your question @arthur. Thanks for your help!